# What is the difference between the reactivity of Lead subacetate and Lead II acetate undergoing a hydrothermal process?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, organometallic-compounds, surfactants

I am attempting to adapt a hydrothermal method for synthesizing $\ce{PbS}$ nanocrystals to my school that contains a mixture of cationic and anionic surfactants sodium dodecyl sulfate (.05 mmol, SDS) and cetyltrimethylammonium bromide (.05 mmol, CTAB) and ethylenediaminetetraacetic acid (.2 mmol, EDTA) as a chelating agent that diminishes the reactivity of lead ions in solution. The lead source within the method is Lead II Acetate and the sulfur source is an organosulfur compound with the formula $\ce{SC(NH2)2}$.

The company that we bought our chemicals from sent us Lead subacetate and while I wait for them to send us the right one back I am wondering if using the appropriate ratio of moles of Lead subacetate which has 3 moles of lead per 1 mole of lead subacetate to the documented lead II acetate which contains 1 mole of lead would lead to lead sulfide $\ce{PbS}$ nanocrystals.

The structure of subacetate contains two crystalline basic acetates containing hydroxide ions in addition to acetate ions. Does the subacetate create a conjugate acid that lowers the pH?

Answer (score 1):

Compared to lead(II) acetate, lead subacetate contains additionally $\ce{2 Pb(OH)2}$. The hydroxide can either be neutralized by protons from EDTA or take part in the hydrolysis of thiourea:

$$\ce{SC(NH2)2 + OH- \rightleftharpoons OC(NH2)2 + HS-}$$

$$\ce{HS- + OH- \rightleftharpoons S^{2-} + H2O}$$

The pH of the solution should be higher unless all hydroxide is neutralized or consumed by the hydrolysis reaction.